# How do I search for videos with 48fps or higher?

Tags: youtube

I tried looking for an advanced search box, but I only see a magnifying glass in the main search box which seems to only perform a title search. Is there a way to filter videos that contain 48fps (frames per second) or higher? I noticed this [60fps list](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbsGxdAPhjv9UrLo19pS8teoRKj7funAy), but it only seems to be a playlist not search results.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an advanced search in the form of filters which you can apply to the search results, but there are no relevant filters past the basic HD quality.

**Update:**

Looks like YouTube has just added a filter for 4K, but no such luck for high FPS yet.

Comment: I put a request in the product forum for YouTube: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/playing-and-watching-videos/discuss-and-give-feedback/chrome/MaWmWnEvt48

Answer (score 1):

There does not currently exist a method for searching for videos with a specific bitrate.

Some content creators may label their videos with the bitrate, allowing you to get a few results from a title search, but this would only represent a small sampling of the total number of videos uploaded in a specific bitrate.

Unless/Until this data is made accessible through Youtube's APIs, or as automated tags which can be searched directly within the site, you cannot search for videos of a specific bitrate.

Comment: Is bitrate the same as frames per second? Can you have a lower bitrate and still have the 48 frames per second or higher? The resolution would just need to be lowered, no?

Comment: Bitrate is the measurement of the volume of data a particular digital media item is encoded and transmitted at. Frames per second is a simple numeric value representing how many individual photos are drawn to the screen per second to create the video. The two numbers may be related, but they are not the same. A high-resolution video with a very low frame rate would still be a large bitrate. A very low resolution video with an extremely high frame rate could still be a rather low bitrate. And different encoding methods also change this equation substantially.

Comment: My question is about videos with high fps, not high bitrate. I feel you used a more generic term thereby providing a confusing answer.

Comment: A "more generic term"? Frame rate is another term for frames per second. It's just shorter. Bitrate can also be referred to as bits per second, from which we can talk about kilo-bits per second (kbps), kilo-bytes per second (KBps), mega-bits per second (mbps), etc.

I simply chose one common term ("rate") in order to highlight the fact that both are measurements (rates) but they are measuring different things. 

I'm sorry that you felt this was more confusing.

Comment: As you stated earlier, bitrate and framerate have a relationship but one does not replace the other. You said so yourself in your previous comment.

Comment: I'm not certain what you're taking issue with. Do you have a further question that needs clarification? Do you feel I disagreed with myself within my answer and comments? Please point out what needs clearing up so that I may attempt to do so.

Comment: Your answer is actually not an answer to the question.